# Парсер PDF и DOCX

Tags: pdf, docx, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, есть ли готовая программа, которая может распарсить таблицы в PDF и DOCX?

Comment: Есть. Например, Adobe Acrobat и Microsoft Word.

Расскажите лучше о своей настоящей проблеме. Вам нужно парсить самому эти форматы? Я не знаю бесплатных парсеров Arcobat, но если вам нужно такое, то явно для коммерческой программы, так что купить платный парсер не должно быть проблемой.

Comment: Есть файл в формате pdf, в котором таблица.
Мне надо все содержимое одного столбца таблицы вывести в отдельный файл, но переписывать все вручную будет слишком долго.
Поэтому и спрашиваю, есть ли какая-нибудь программа, позволяющая вывести эти данные и, если возможно, чтобы еще и между выводимыми данными можно было расставлять нужные строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи оптимальным и, с большой долей вероятности, единственным решением будет написать парсер самому. Честно говоря, не могу представить готовое решение с нужной вам степенью кастомизации.

Для pdf используйте, например, [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), а для docx - [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295(v=office.12).aspx) или хотя бы даже [Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kw65a0we.aspx)